# Tomcat Connection Pooling Multiple Data Sources

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

If I have configured a JNDI resource in Tomcat and in my code I create two DataSource objects referencing the same JNDI resource will this create two different connection pools or will the DataSources share the same connection pool?  If possible could you provide resources that support your answer, I have searched all over and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will use the same connection pool.

What you are declaring is a reference to the real connection pool declared on tomcat so in you case you have 2 references.

If you want to be sure make a test by leaking a connection on one datasource and display size of the 2 datasources.

As for reference look at oracle jndi tutorials and tomcat doc configuration of connectio pools.

Regards

Philippe M.

Comment: I did some further research, I believe this Oracle Document explains it best: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html

Answer (score 2):

When you say "create two DataSource Objects" are you actually creating the objects or are you getting them from JNDI?  Can you post a snippet of code?

If you get a DataSource via JNDI its going to be a Pooled DataSource which you can safely use, it will be the same pool.  If your actually creating new objects then its a different story.

Comment: I don't have the code handy but I'm getting them using the initial context similar to this line:  DataSource datasource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);

Comment: You're going to be retrieving, not creating, the DataSource, so its always going to point to the DataSource Pool, you won't be creating new pools.